# Related posts on my blog (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

So I bought a template and hosting from ghost.org. Unfortunately, it uses handlebars, a language I'm not very familiar with. I figured it out, but then when I implemented this jquery file for adding related posts to the bottom of the page using tags created in handlebars, it did not work. When I looked over the file it seemed to be fine. So I'm wondering if any of you can find a bug or error with the prototype based programming. Credits to dane cando at github for the file, but it isnt working. Below are the javascript for the related posts function and the ul class from the handlebars file.

#### JavScript File

```
(function($) {
  defaults = {
    feed: '/rss',
    titleClass: '.post-title',
    tagsClass: '.post-meta',
    limit: 5,
    debug: true,
    template: '<li><a href="{url}">{title}</a></li>',
    messages: {
      noRelated: 'No related posts were found.'
    }
  };

  function RelatedPosts(element, options) {
    this.element = element;
    this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
    this.parseRss();
  };

  RelatedPosts.prototype.displayRelated = function(posts) {
    var self = this, count = 0;
    this._currentPostTags = this.getCurrentPostTags(this.options.tagsClass);
    var related = this.matchByTag(this._currentPostTags, posts), options = this.options;
    related.forEach(function(post) {
      var template = options.template.replace(/{[^{}]+}/g, function(key) {
        return post[key.replace(/[{}]+/g, '')] || '';
      });
      if (count < self.options.limit) {
        $(self.element).append($(template));
      }
      count++;
    });
    if (count == 0) {
      $(this.element).append($('<li>' + this.messages.noRelated + '</li>'));
    }
  };

  RelatedPosts.prototype.parseRss = function(pageNum, prevId, feeds) {
    var page = pageNum || 1, prevId = prevId || '', feeds = feeds || [], self = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: this.options.feed + '/' + page,
        type: 'GET'
      })
      .done(function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        var curId = $(data).find('item > guid').text();
        if (curId != prevId) {
          feeds.push(data);
          self.parseRss(page + 1, curId, feeds);
        }
        else {
          var posts = self.getPosts(feeds);
          self.displayRelated(posts);
        }
      })
      .fail(function(e) {
        self.reportError(e);
      });
  };

  RelatedPosts.prototype.getCurrentPostTitle = function(titleClass) {
    if (titleClass[0] != '.') {
      titleClass = '.' + titleClass;
    }
    var postTitle = $(titleClass).text();
    if (postTitle.length < 1) {
      this.reportError("Couldn't find the post title with class: " + titleClass);
    }
    return postTitle;
  };

  RelatedPosts.prototype.getCurrentPostTags = function(tagsClass) {
    if (tagsClass[0] != '.') {
      tagsClass = '.' + tagsClass;
    }
    var tags = [];
    $(tagsClass + ' a').each(function() {
      tags.push($(this).text());
    });
    if (tags.length < 1) {
      this.reportError("Couldn't find any tags in this post");
    }
    return tags;
  };

  RelatedPosts.prototype.getPosts = function(feeds) {
    var posts = [], items = [];
    feeds.forEach(function(feed) {
      items = $.merge(items, $(feed).find('item'));
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
     var item = $(items[i]);
      if (item.find('title').text() !== this.getCurrentPostTitle(this.options.titleClass)) {
        posts.push({
          title: item.find('title').text(),
          url: item.find('link').text(),
          content: item.find('description').text(),
          tags: $.map(item.find('category'), function(elem) {
            return $(elem).text();
          })
        });
      }
    }
    if (posts.length < 1) {
      this.reportError("Couldn't find any posts in feed: " + feed);
    }
    return posts;
  };

  RelatedPosts.prototype.reportError = function(error) {
    if (this.options.debug) {
      $(this.element).append($('<li>' + error + '</li>'));
    }
  };

  RelatedPosts.prototype.matchByTag = function(postTags, posts) {
    var matches = [];
    posts.forEach(function(post) {
      var beenAdded = false;
      post.tags.forEach(function(tag) {
        postTags.forEach(function(postTag) {
          if (postTag.toLowerCase() === tag.toLowerCase() && !beenAdded) {
            matches.push(post);
            beenAdded = true;
          }
        });
      });
    });
    if (matches.length < 1) {
      this.reportError("There are no closely related posts");
    }
    return matches;
  };

  $.fn.ghostRelated = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
      new RelatedPosts(this, options);
    });
  };

})(jQuery);

$('.related-posts').ghostRelated();
```

#### HTML List

```
<ul class="related-posts">

</ul>
```

Comment: any developer tools console errors?

Comment: is `http://yoursite/rss/1` a valid url?

Comment: no, where do ya see that though haha @JaromandaX

Comment: well ... I don't know what `yoursite` is ... but the code above refers to `/rss/?` where ? is a number - it's the `feed` - I assume there was some server side code you needed to implement for all this

Comment: oh yeah it links to an xml file @JaromandaX